# Allocating arrays slows calculations

Tags: c++, arrays, performance

I'm working on code that finds the most similar vectors among two sets as quickly as possible, using cosine similarity.
The code uses raw arrays (for speed and simplicity), and I started noticing that when I allocated more arrays, the program got slower, even if I didn't change my calculations at all.  I managed to distill the program down to the following hundred or so lines without losing the problem:

```
#include <iostream>

const int vec_len = 192;

struct fvec
{
    int64_t nvec;
    short int **vecs;
#ifdef PARTIALS
    int **partials;
#endif
    fvec(int size)
    {
        nvec = size;
        vecs = new short int *[nvec];
#ifdef PARTIALS
        partials = new int *[nvec];
#endif
        for (int64_t i = 0; i < nvec; i++)
        {
            vecs[i] = new short int[vec_len];
#ifdef PARTIALS
            partials[i] = new int[vec_len];
#endif
            for (int j = 0; j < vec_len; j++) vecs[i][j] = std::rand() * 10000 / RAND_MAX;
        }
    }
    ~fvec()
    {
        for (int64_t i = 0; i < nvec; i++)
        {
            delete[] vecs[i];
#ifdef PARTIALS
            delete[] partials[i];
#endif
        }
        delete[] vecs;
#ifdef PARTIALS
        delete[] partials;
#endif
    }
};

struct cvec
{
    int nvec;
    short int **vecs;
#ifdef PARTIALS
    int **partials;
#endif
    cvec(int size)
    {
        nvec = size;
        vecs = new short int *[nvec];
#ifdef PARTIALS
        partials = new int *[nvec];
#endif
        for (int nv = 0; nv < nvec; nv++)
        {
            vecs[nv] = new short int[vec_len];
#ifdef PARTIALS
            partials[nv] = new int[vec_len];
#endif
            for (int i = 0; i < vec_len; i++) vecs[nv][i] = std::rand() * 10000 / RAND_MAX;
        }
    }
    ~cvec()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < nvec; i++)
        {
            delete[] vecs[i];
#ifdef PARTIALS
            delete[] partials[i];
#endif
        }
        delete[] vecs;
#ifdef PARTIALS
        delete[] partials;
#endif
    }
};

float sim(short int *a, short int *b)
{
    int ret = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < vec_len; i++) ret += a[i] * b[i];
    return ret;
}

void iterative_nn(const cvec &c, const fvec &f, int *results)
{
    for (int64_t i = 0; i < f.nvec; i++)
    {
        results[i] = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < c.nvec; j++)
        {
            float tmpsim = sim(f.vecs[i], c.vecs[j]);
            if (tmpsim > results[i]) results[i] = tmpsim;
        }
        if (i % 100 == 0) std::cout << "\r" << i << std::flush;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int res[5000];
    iterative_nn(cvec{100000}, fvec{5000}, res);
    std::cout << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

As you can see, I've got two classes holding the two sets of arrays.  I'm filling the two sets of arrays with random values (for the demonstration), then calling a function that iterates through all the arrays and calculates their similarities.
When I add another set of arrays to each class by specifying -DPARTIALS on the command line, the program slows to about half the speed on my computer.  Clearly, the only lines being touched by that directive are the allocation and deallocation of the additional array!
Furthermore, the extra time is not being spent on allocation and deallocation, which take less than a second in either case.  The extra time is spent in the iterative search, which is untouched by the directive (or so I thought).  Thus, my question:  what is it about merely allocating the extra arrays that slows down my program by half?

The code above wants compiling with -std=c++11.  It runs in about 25 seconds or 1 minute for me if I use -O3.

Comment: Dynamic allocation and deallocation are expensive, `std::vector` would help, but since the sizes are fixed, why not just a normal array on the stack or `std::array`?

Comment: So, you're confused because youe expected dynamic memory allocation to be free in terms of performance? Is that the same as expecting the implementation of `new` to be 0 lines of code? Otherwise, if you think it does some work on your behalf, why does it surprise you that it also needs time to do it? I'm confused by your confusion. :) Avoiding dynamic memory allocations in "inner loop" type of code is a very basic optimization trick, which it seems you've just been taught.

Comment: @unwind Well, the OP claims the slowdown is *not* in the allocation, but in the search (which doesn't actually use allocation). It would certainly be interesting to see where this conviction is coming from, though.

Comment: "The code uses raw arrays (for speed and simplicity)" as soon as I read this, I know there will be trouble.

Comment: So, you wanted speed and simplicity, and you've now got code which is slow, and you don't understand why. Perhaps raw arrays were not the greatest way to achieve speed and simplicity, then. ;)

Comment: @Agnew I assumed it was obvious that the slowdown was in the search rather than the allocation, because the time between the start of the program and the call to iterative_nn is about the same (less than a second) in both cases.  If the difference in time was due to the allocation step, we would expect there to be a long wait before the call to iterative_nn, and then for the search to take the same amount of time in either case.  Is this assumption incorrect?

Comment: @JesseGood Your comment suggests two things I thought I knew about C++ are incorrect:  First, that std::vector and kin allocate dynamic memory; second, that stack arrays can only last as long as the function declaring them and therefore cannot be used in class members.  Am I wrong on these counts?  I would love to use stack arrays if I could.

Comment: @MatthewSchauer: `std::vector` allocates memory dynamically, however it is designed to be efficient so you may see a speed up by using it. Class members will be valid for as long as the class contains them is valid. There is no reason why you couldn't change the code to `short int vecs[nvec][nvec];`, etc. as far as I can see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two factor which cause the performance drop:

1. More cache hit failure will happen when CPU load the data from memory in the calculation loop.
2. The new and delete take times.

I have moved following code into an separate loop it improve the performance significantly, which I believe is because of item #1.

```
#ifdef PARTIALS
            partials[nv] = new int[vec_len];
#endif
```

- Orignal code WITHOUT PARTIALS: 1m16s.
- Orignal code WITH PARTIALS: 1m40s.
- Separate loop WITHOUT PARTIALS: 1m16s.
- Separate loop WITH PARTIALS: 1m20s.

So in my case the #1 takes about 4seconds. And The cache miss takes about 20seconds.

The changed code is as following (I'm build with O3 and not with c11) :

```
#include <iostream>

const int vec_len = 192;

struct fvec
{
    int64_t nvec;
    short int **vecs;
#ifdef PARTIALS
    int **partials;
#endif
    fvec(int size)
    {
        nvec = size;
        vecs = new short int *[nvec];
#ifdef PARTIALS
        partials = new int *[nvec];
#endif
#ifdef PARTIALS // <<<<< put it here in an separator loop.
        for (int64_t i = 0; i < nvec; i++)
        {
            partials[i] = new int[vec_len];
        }
#endif
        for (int64_t i = 0; i < nvec; i++)
        {
            vecs[i] = new short int[vec_len];
            for (int j = 0; j < vec_len; j++) vecs[i][j] = std::rand() * 10000 / RAND_MAX;
        }
    }
    ~fvec()
    {
        for (int64_t i = 0; i < nvec; i++)
        {
            delete[] vecs[i];
#ifdef PARTIALS
            delete[] partials[i];
#endif
        }
        delete[] vecs;
#ifdef PARTIALS
        delete[] partials;
#endif
    }
};

struct cvec
{
    int nvec;
    short int **vecs;
#ifdef PARTIALS
    int **partials;
#endif
    cvec(int size)
    {
        nvec = size;
        vecs = new short int *[nvec];
#ifdef PARTIALS
        partials = new int *[nvec];
#endif

#ifdef PARTIALS // <<<<< put it here in an separator loop.
        for (int nv = 0; nv < nvec; nv++)
        {
            partials[nv] = new int[vec_len];
        }
#endif

        for (int nv = 0; nv < nvec; nv++)
        {
            vecs[nv] = new short int[vec_len];
            for (int i = 0; i < vec_len; i++) vecs[nv][i] = std::rand() * 10000 / RAND_MAX;
        }
    }
    ~cvec()
    {
#ifdef PARTIALS 
        for (int i = 0; i < nvec; i++)
        {
            delete[] partials[i];
        }
#endif

        for (int i = 0; i < nvec; i++)
        {
            delete[] vecs[i];
        }
        delete[] vecs;
#ifdef PARTIALS
        delete[] partials;
#endif
    }
};

float sim(short int *a, short int *b)
{
    int ret = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < vec_len; i++) ret += a[i] * b[i];
    return ret;
}

void iterative_nn(const cvec &c, const fvec &f, int *results)
{
    for (int64_t i = 0; i < f.nvec; i++)
    {
        results[i] = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < c.nvec; j++)
        {
            float tmpsim = sim(f.vecs[i], c.vecs[j]);
            if (tmpsim > results[i]) results[i] = tmpsim;
        }
        if (i % 100 == 0) std::cout << "\r" << i << std::flush;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int res[5000];
    iterative_nn(cvec(100000), fvec(5000), res);
    std::cout << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Wow, right you are!  Thank you!  But I'm still not sure of the cause.  I thought cache misses might be involved, but if the partials memory isn't ever used, shouldn't it be eliminated from the cache very quickly?

Comment: @MatthewSchauer The reason is the memory allocated without `PARTIALS` will have good continuity. You can print out the memory address of `vecs[i]`, in my machine each block are adjacent without `PARTIALS`. And I also like to say the memory continuity in `cvec` is the major reason, because it is been access in the inner loop of `iterative_nn`, just disable PARTIALS surrounded code inside the `cvec` will make it almost as faster as without PARTIALS in the whole program.

Comment: @MatthewSchauer, and another thing which will confirm this is that if you change the `i++` to `i--` in the loop of `sim` will make it run about 1m40seconds without PARTIALS.